# Is it a good practice to override `setMeasuredDimension()` or `getMeasuredWidth()` in custom View?

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a scenario:

ViewA `extends` ViewB, both override `onMeasure()` and call `setMeasuredDimension()`. ViewA sets its width to be `10dp` whereas ViewB sets its width to be `20dp`. Now if I call `super.getMeasuredWidth()` from ViewB at the end of `onMeasure()` to get the width of ViewA, I get `20dp`. The reason is obvious when ViewA is done measuring itself, ViewB calls `setMeasuredDimension()` which in turn overwrite the old values.

Now the obvious solution is to override related methods. My question is, is it a good practice to override `setMeasuredDimension()` or `getMeasuredWidth()`, `getMeasuredHeight()` in custom `View`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, solution was simple. In `onMeasure()` of ViewB, I collected ViewA's width and height immediately and then called `setMeasuredDimension()`:

```
super.onMeasure(wSpec, hSpec);
final int superWidth = super.getMeasuredWidth();
final int superHeight = super.getMeasuredHeight();
setMeasuredDimension(w, h);

// use superWidth and superHeight here
```

and that's it.